# Angular seems to convert timezone automatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime

I use `$resource` to make `GET` request to the server and I get datetime (from Network tab of Chrome Developer Tool) with timezone data for example: `2016-01-27T14:30:00.000-07:00` however as soon as results get resolved with `$promise` under `then` block it seems to translate that timezone automatically to my browser's local time.

so I call below code:

```
return testService.get(id)
  .then(function(result){
    console.log(result);
  });
```

**test.service.js:**

```
this.get = function(id){
  return resource.get({id: id}).$promise;
}
```

The result of `console.log(result)` above has something like `28-Jan-2016 08:30`

Is there a reason why this is being translated automatically?

How can I stop this as it's rendering wrong datetime on the template

Comment: This has nothing to do with angular and everything to do with how the javascript `Date` object works in browsers. Not a simple subject....do some reading

Answer (score 0):

It's not angular, who does that, it's javascript. You can read more here, section **About UTC**

http://www.elated.com/articles/working-with-dates/

*All dates and times are stored internally in JavaScript using UTC. When you use the above, non-UTC functions to get dates and times, JavaScript converts the time back into the local computer's time locale first. However, the UTC functions below will return times and dates in UTC format instead.*